# No sound in Telegram using usb sound card

Tags: sound, usb

I've bought a sound card behringer u-phoria umc204hd and faced 2 issues:

First. There is no sound in Telegram. Ether in videos or voice messages. And only this application has this issue, I've tried chrome, OBS, Davinci Resolve, VLC.

Second. Sound speed is slightly slow. So the lag is about 5 sec. per minute, and it increases. I've found that it should be solved by re-enable device in pavucontrol, from time to time.

I don't know if these two issues are connected or not, but I will be happy if you help with one problem at least.

I am using **Ubuntu 20.04** and tried **Telegram Desktop 2.1.7, 3.2.4 from site and 3.2.2 from snap**

UPD. It seems, I've fixed sound speed issues by uncommenting  in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`:

```
 default-sample-rate = 48000
 alternate-sample-rate = 44100
```

But still no audio in Telegram though.

pavucontrol displays some output levels while there is no sound:

[image]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and Telegram are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 and Telegram Desktop 2.1.7

Comment: Pls include the versions in your question. I would try installing the latest version of [Telegram - 3.2.4](https://desktop.telegram.org/). Click on **"Get Telegram for Linix"** Follow the prompts to open with **Archive Manager**. By default it will extracted in your home directory in the **Downloads/telegram** folder. Then run `./Telegram` This is the standalone version (Not a software package).

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I don't think Telegram Desktop 2.1.7 needs to be uninstalled but it would not hurt.

Comment: Same behavior in 3.2.4 from site and 3.2.2 from snap

Comment: Try resetting the pulseaudio configuration by running the following commands: `mv ~/.config/pulse/ ~/.config/pulse.old` then run `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio`

Comment: @stumblebee just tried, no any errors and no positive effects in Telegram

Comment: Would using the web version of Telegram be a reasonable workaround?

Comment: You clearly have everything set up correctly from the information you have provided. If all else fails and you have not done so already, I would send a email to [Telegram Support](https://telegram.org/support). Telegram should use the default sound device defined in your Desktop settings Just like your other working applications do without prejudice. You can then give yourself the 150 bounty by answering your own question and share with the rest of us!  :-D    BTW +1 on your question!

Comment: I've found, that since the output is 4.0, there is front and back channels, the phones plays only one of them, maybe telegram outputs in the second, maybe it is the case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the issue. Behringer u-phoria umc204hd has 4.0 audio - 2 separate stereo channels, but then using phones, you can get only one of them. While other apps play in both, Telegram plays only in one of them. So to fix that, you just need to switch output in phones by pressing **Monitor A/B** switcher on the device

[image]

Comment: Excellent work! Now accept your own answer!

Comment: Elaborate on "pressing **Monitor A/B switcher**" I assume it is a function on the Behringer device.

Comment: @stumblebee a physical button, basically

Comment: 10-4! I was requesting for you to elaborate in your answer so it would be not confused with a software setting.